# MySQL: Using LIKE generating more results than what I need

Tags: mysql

It seems like my LIKE mySQL command is generated more results than I would like it to. I don't understand why, and I was wondering if someone can help me accomplish my goal by helping me understand why my query isn't working as expected. I took off the left '%' from my query which helped a little bit, but its still generating a lot of results that I don't need.

For example:

```
User input ($searchword): 'ad' => returns[4]: 
                     'Adele Necklaces, 
                      Adwarrior Swords, 
                      Affirmative T-shirt, 
                      Agtec Radio'

Trying to get THESE results for user input($searchword): 'ad' => returns[2]: 
                                                   'Adelete Neckalces, 
                                                    Adwarrior Swords'
```

SQL Command:

```
("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE '".$searchword."%'")
```

Comment: With a % to the left of `$searchword` these results make sense. I don't think you removed it in the correct place.

Comment: Adelete Neckalces, Adwarrior Swords is exactly what i would have expected from that Query. Or is that the result you want to archieve?

Comment: I would have no idea why a search for `ad%` would return the last two results you have shown.  Are you sure you are modifying your search string somewhere? Have you looked at the actual query running that gets sent to the database to make sure it is what you expected?

Comment: Affirmative T-shirt being in the results for %ad% baffles me. Baffles!

Comment: I know! me too! the first two results are as expected, after that, it pretty much starts with 'a' then the second letter is alphabetical...

Comment: Provide the schema and result of `var_dump("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE '".$searchword."%';");`

Answer (score 0):

My friend, I believe you are mistaken.  [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) works exactly as you expect.

```
mysql> create table searchterms (term varchar(64), key(term) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into searchterms (term) values 
('Adele Necklaces'), ('Adwarrior Swords'),
('Affirmative T-shirt'), ('Agtec Radio');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> set @st='ad';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @st='ad';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from searchterms where term like concat(@st, '%');
+------------------+
| term             |
+------------------+
| Adele Necklaces  |
| Adwarrior Swords |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why its returning more results than 2 in my case? For me the first two results are as expected, after that, the terms pretty much starts with an 'a' then the second letter is alphabetical...

Comment: Removing the left `%` will ignore any matches to the left of the search string.

Comment: @MHZ what does your schema look like?